# Trying to install turtle in cmd (python)

Tags: python, python-turtle

after i write pip install turtle in cmd, this message in pressented to me.
anyone knows what to do??

`C:\>pip install turtle`

```
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qv3xb6xg\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qv3xb6xg\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2tmj1fl2'
         cwd: C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qv3xb6xg\turtle\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qv3xb6xg\turtle\setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Answer (score 2):

You already have turtle installed. However, if you get un error while trying to import turtle library, you most likely named your python file "turtle" so the module thinks you're trying to import the file that you're on instead of the real turtle file. So if that is the case try changing the name and it should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install `turtle`, it's already built in, and so, pip can't install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `PythonTurtle` package. You can do this like this:

```
pip install PythonTurtle
```